# Add jQuery dependency in angularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How I can add jquery-ui.js to my controller.I'm new to the ui-router

```
.state('new_patient', {
            url: '/newpatient', 
            templateUrl: window.localStorage.getItem('contextPath') + '/module/laboratory/newpatient',
            controller: 'PatientController',
            resolve: {
                deps: function($q, $rootScope) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var dependencies = ['jquery-ui'];
                    require(dependencies, function() {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                            deferred.resolve();
                        });
                    });

                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
        });
```

OR  as follows

```
resolve: {        async: ['jquery-ui',  function($) {            
        }]
    }
```

pls help..
Its for working of an accordion.. Thanks in advance for replies.

Comment: Why not https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion

Comment: Why not linking the js in index.html just like any other lib? Are you trying to implement lazy loading? Try: oclazyload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.state('new_patient', {
            url: '/newpatient', 
            templateUrl: window.localStorage.getItem('contextPath') + '/module/laboratory/newpatient',
            controller: 'PatientController',
            resolve: {
                deps: function ($q){
                var defer = $q.defer();

                require(['js/core/jquery-ui'], function() {

                        defer.resolve(); 

                });

             return defer.promise;
            }
            }
        });
```